# MagnificPopup not working on first click using on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have delegated to `$(document)` a `click` method for a dynamically-added element with a class of `.popup-youtube`. the only thing is, i just can't get the popup to work properly.

Here's my script:

```
$(this).on("click", ".popup-youtube", function(e){

        // prevent default action
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).magnificPopup({
            type: 'iframe',
            iframe: {
                markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
                    '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                    '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                    '</div>', // HTML markup of popup, `mfp-close` will be replaced by the close button
                patterns: {
                    youtube: {
                        index: 'youtube.com/', // String that detects type of video (in this case YouTube). Simply via url.indexOf(index).
                        id: 'v=', // String that splits URL in a two parts, second part should be %id%
                        // Or null - full URL will be returned
                        // Or a function that should return %id%, for example:
                        // id: function(url) { return 'parsed id'; }
                        src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1' // URL that will be set as a source for iframe.
                    },
                    vimeo: {
                        index: 'vimeo.com/',
                        id: '/',
                        src: '//player.vimeo.com/video/%id%?autoplay=1'
                    },
                    gmaps: {
                        index: '//maps.google.',
                        src: '%id%&output=embed'
                    }
                },
                srcAction: 'iframe_src'
            }
        });
    });
```

Anyone have any tips on this? your help would gladly be appreciated.

Comment: Change it from `$(this).on("click", ".popup-youtube"` to `$(document).on("click", ".popup-youtube"`

Comment: I've tried it @RobSchmuecker. unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this - chaining the `open` method after you are initialising the `popup`

```
$(document).on("click", ".popup-youtube", function(e){

        // prevent default action
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).magnificPopup({
            type: 'iframe',
            iframe: {
                markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
                    '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                    '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                    '</div>', // HTML markup of popup, `mfp-close` will be replaced by the close button
                patterns: {
                    youtube: {
                        index: 'youtube.com/', // String that detects type of video (in this case YouTube). Simply via url.indexOf(index).
                        id: 'v=', // String that splits URL in a two parts, second part should be %id%
                        // Or null - full URL will be returned
                        // Or a function that should return %id%, for example:
                        // id: function(url) { return 'parsed id'; }
                        src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1' // URL that will be set as a source for iframe.
                    },
                    vimeo: {
                        index: 'vimeo.com/',
                        id: '/',
                        src: '//player.vimeo.com/video/%id%?autoplay=1'
                    },
                    gmaps: {
                        index: '//maps.google.',
                        src: '%id%&output=embed'
                    }
                },
                srcAction: 'iframe_src'
            }
        }).magnificPopup('open');
    });
```

Comment: I have the same scenario, and adding `magnificPopup('open');` works but the close button when the popup is open doesnot work. Instead after the close button is clicked, the video starts again.